# how to add characters to character array

Tags: c, arduino, nodemcu

i want add characters to a character array. my code is

```
char x[100];
int i;
void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
}
void loop() {
for ( i=0; i<11;i++)
{
  x[i]=(char)i;
}
Serial.println(strlen(x));
for (i=0;i<11;i++)
{
  Serial.print(x[i]);
}

delay(1000);
}
```

i am expecting the array to be x[0] = 0 ,x[1] = 1, x[2] = 2......x[10]=10

but the array seems to be empty as `Serial.println(strlen(x));` returns 0 
and  `Serial.print(x[i]);` prints nothing. 
how do i add character to an array???

Comment: @RoadRunner; No UB, the first char is already a 0...

Comment: @RoadRunner Beyond that, there already is a `\0` at the end of the array (and everywhere else in the array initially). That is a global variable, and as such has static linkage and therefore initially zero-filled if the toolchain is compliant with the language standard.

Comment: i tried adding '\0' at the end of array still  Serial.print(x[i]); prints nothing andSerial.println(strlen(x)); returns 0;

Comment: @RishikeshAyre Read Serge's answer below. It is probably what you want, though you never actually stated what the code was *supposed* to do, only that what it *was* doing wasn't desired.

Comment: @SergeBallesta thank you . it worked  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oups, a C string is by convention a char array terminated with a null byte. All `strxx` functions follow this convention.

As the first character of the array is... 0, `strlen` finds a terminating null at index 0 and correctly says that the length of the string is 0.

In addition, all characters with code 0 to 10 (assuming ASCII) are control non printable characters.

I assume that what you wanted to do is

```
for ( i=0; i<11;i++)
{
  x[i]= '0' + i; /* 0 to 9 and : */
}
x[11] = '\0';   /* terminate the array with a null to make it a C string */
```

Answer (score 0):

replace : `x[i] = (char)i;`
to: `x[i]=(char) ( ((int) '0') + i );`
and add `x[11] = '\0';`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.